# How to add rewrite rule to Azure web.config so that certain requests are not redirected?

Tags: azure, redirect, web-config, url-rewrite-module

How to add a URL Rewrite rule so that requests from user agents – `ReadyForRequest/1.0+(HealthCheck)` & `HealthCheck/1.0` are not redirected ? I need this so Azure app service health check can work.

I found [many SO posts about redirecting urls](https://www.google.com/?q=redirect+url+with+rewrite+rules+web.config+stackoverflow) but I can't found SO posts for preventing redirection for certain requests.

This post is to add answer to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65627278/how-to-fix-warning-application-evaluated-unhealthy-due-to-redirection-on-azu), but I only want to focus on the real problem because my previous post seems gained attention to the wrong topic.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can add `web.config` in your project. It work for me.

[image]

## Method 2

In `Startup.cs`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");

        endpoints.MapGet("/{**path}", async context =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(
                "Navigate to /health to see the health status.");
        });
    });
}
```

In `web.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true"/>
    <httpCompression>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true"/>
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/health" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks but I use Azure App Service, WordPress & PHP so I can't use Startup.cs & I can't use the web.config on your health check as well.

Comment: @Dika You add web.config tag in this post. ^-^

Comment: @Dika Do you have .htaccess file in this site ?